# Collection::orders does not exist - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collection

iniciano esse tópico dizendo que sou novo no Laravel, mas vamos lá, estou tendo um problema de collection, está dando um erro dizendo que não existe sendo que fiz essa conexão no Model como mostrado abaixo.

Order Controller

```
public function index()
{
    
    $customer = Customer::all();
    $orders = $customer->orders()->get();

    return view('admin.orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

Customer Model

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

Order Model

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro acontece porque você está tentando executar o método do `Model` em uma `Collection`, o método `all()` retorna uma coleção (que pode ser entendido como um array) de Models. Para carregar as relações pela coleção use o método `load()`, conforme a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```php
$customers = Customer::all();
$customers->load('orders');
// obter orders do primeiro customer:
$orders = $customers[0]->orders
```

Como você usou `$customer` no singular acho possível que o problema seja que você quer obter apenas um registro, para isso o código deve ser algo assim:

```php
$customer = Customer::find($id); // retorna só um Model
$orders = $customer->orders; // faz a mesma coisa que $customer->orders()->get()
```

Comment: Então Pedro, to tentando trazer as informações dos Pedidos, que junto com ele tem um cliente, nesse jeito que você mostrou, ele só traz informações dos clientes e nenhuma informação do pedido. Seria melhor eu trazer as informações do pedido e depois puxar o cliente?

Comment: acabei fazendo ao contrário e funcionou, $orders = $this->order->paginate(10); $orders = $orders->load('customer');